# Detecting anomalous/bad files

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition

I am new to machine learning and I'm working on a project in which I need to detect possible anomalous files based on the content and inner structure of it.

So let's say that my normal file follows the following pattern:

```
BookName    BookSize    BookRecords
B1            20mb        1000
B2            15mb        750
B3            16mb        1500
```

A possible anomalous or suspicious file could be the following:

```
BookName    Book$iZe    BookRecords
XXXXX         20mb        1000
B2            15mb        null
B3            seven-mb    500.7893
```

`XXXXX` for a BookName looks suspicious; having a `null` number of records is also suspicious as well as having a double value; having a `string (seven-mb)` on the booksize is also suspicious; The `BookSize name` is also not written correctly; etc etc

I need to implement a program that detects these possible anomalous or suspicious patterns and tells the user that the following file might be a bad file.

I know this falls within the supervised Machine Learning techniques, but I don't know to which specific area does it falls in. Am I correct in assuming this is a classification problem? If so, which technique should I follow: Naïve Bayes, Decision Trees, Neural Networks...?